# Trigger something only on the first of (potentially many) jQuery mouseup events

Tags: jquery, mouseup

I have

```
$('#myElem').mouseup(function(e){

  isMouseDown = false;

});
```

What I want to do is trigger a single event (e.g. an alert, or ++1 to a counter) only on the *first* of what might be a number of mousedown events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple bindings and are filtering, you can use [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) within the event and stop it from going up the event list. Though it's still not clear what you mean about "first of what might be a number of mousedown events". (Bound to multiple selectors relating to same element, bound to children within a parent, ...)

You can also use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and bind to an event only *after* a previous event has occurred. Likewise, you can add/remove binding based on specific events.

Comment: .one() was the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, this one:

```
$('#myElem').mouseup(function(e) {

    isMouseDown = false;
    return false;

});
```

And this one:

```
$('#myElem').mouseup(function(e) {

    isMouseDown = false;
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```